# Sort DynamoDB Data using query other than the sort key

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to DynamoDB and Python & having a problem where I have to query DynamoDB and sort the data in descending order as per the date column which is not a sort key.
I did not find any way to sort data using Boto3 API.

After 2 days of extensive research on stackoverflow, and other sites only answer I got that it is not possible. So just putting my final effort on it.

The Date column is of String type having data in format YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.
Currently I am using this below code to retrieve the data in Json format.

```py
result = TABLE.query(
    KeyConditionExpression="partitionKey = :pk",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":pk": partitionKey
    }
)
```

This is the first & good approach to sort on queries but if it is not possible any reference to sort data using python library which transforms `result["items"]` and respond with the sorted json.

The `result["items"]` is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "colV",
        "dateColumn": "20231104_122600",
        # ...
    },
{
        "id": "colV",
        "dateColumn": "20231105_122600",
        # ...
    },
{
        "id": "colX",
        "dateColumn": "20231114_122600",
        # ...
    },
{
        "id": "colX",
        "dateColumn": "20231105_122600",
        # ...
    },
    # ...
]
```

Small correction for clarity:
Data should be formatted on the basis of the id using dateColumn: so for record it should be like: Desc order of date

```
[
{
    "id": "colV",
    "dateColumn": "20231105_122600",
    # ...
},
{
    "id": "colV",
    "dateColumn": "20231104_122600",
    # ...
},

{
    "id": "colX",
    "dateColumn": "20231114_122600",
    # ...
},
{
    "id": "colX",
    "dateColumn": "20231105_122600",
    # ...
},
# ...
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sort key on the table already? If you do you have 2 choices:

1. Create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with date as the sort key. That will allow automatic sorting based on date
2. Sort on the client side using python's [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function.

```
sorted_list = sorted(result['Items'], key=lambda x: x['dateColumn'])
```

Comment: I do have the sort key but it is not required in this case. Can I still use the GSI?
For your second answer I  have updated my question to sort it my 2 values.

Comment: Yes a GSI will still work. For your second point, when you do a Query, you will only have a single `id` in the list, it won't have multiple.